# EXCEL VBA: Double Condition Satisfied and then Delete Row

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

Folks,

I have a two conditions to be met. One: In the first column the numbers can be either 1, 2 or 2,3 or 3,4 and Two: the last column needs to be F,F in subsequent rows. If this condition is satisfied, I need to delete the entire row with the larger integer from the first column. The check must happen two rows at a time.
I cant seem to wrap my head around this. Y'all have some hints??

Thank you!

Edit:

Level 0 remains unchanged and fixed.

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Showing 2 rows of data is hardly considered a good sample. Can you add some more data here and highlight the rows that should be deleted based on your criteria.

Comment: I added another picture.

Comment: where did the lvl 0 come from? looks inconsistent with your explination

Comment: Level 0 is not to be changed.

Comment: is level 0 always at the top? so the pairs always start after level 0? the point is you have to explain the whole problem or you are going to get help that doesn't actually fit your problem. Do you have any code to share here? what have you tired?

Comment: Im trying to do it using an If statement, but im kind of new to coding. From what i understand - a double if with a counter increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would benefit from array checks and not deleting inside the loop (using a `UNION`). Either way, this works given your criteria

Note: I am using `Column A` for `lvl` and `Column B` for `Stock` so you will need to make that fit your data. This also assumes the relevant data starts at row 3 *(i.e. ignore row 1 for header and ignore row 2 for your lvl 0 value)*.

---

```
Sub try()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim v1 As Range, v2 As Range

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 3 Step -2
    Set v1 = ws.Range("A" & i)
    Set v2 = ws.Range("A" & i - 1)
    
    If (v1 = 1 And v2 = 2) Or (v1 = 2 And v2 = 1) Or _
       (v1 = 2 And v2 = 3) Or (v1 = 3 And v2 = 2) Or _
       (v1 = 3 And v2 = 4) Or (v1 = 4 And v2 = 3) Then
       
        If ws.Range("B" & i) = "F" And ws.Range("B" & i - 1) = "F" Then
            If v1 > v2 Then
                ws.Range("A" & v1.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                ws.Range("A" & v2.Row).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
  Set v1 = Nothing
  Set v2 = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the set up I used so the ranges and columns were based off this photo. You will need to make the updates to fit your spreadsheet. Items in red were deleted by macro which fits your criteria

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I would have never got the part where '(v1 = 2 And v2 = 1)' and so on. It would have taken me forever.